Blocked CORS-request from a file that has the needed headers
I'm trying to have a game I've made access an API that I don't want exposed so I'm trying to request it from proxy.php but it keeps on getting blocked.
Code
This is the code in the proxy.php file:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'php_errors.log');

function logMessage($message) {
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i:s] ') . $message . PHP_EOL, 3, 'php_errors.log');
}

logMessage("Script started");

// CORS headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// Handle preflight requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    logMessage("Preflight request received");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
    header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
    exit;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");

logMessage("Received a request");

$apiKey = '***********';

$inputData = file_get_contents('php://input');
logMessage("Received input: " . $inputData);

$data = json_decode($inputData, true);
$prompt = $data['prompt'] ?? null;

if (!$prompt) {
    logMessage("Error: No prompt received");
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'No prompt received']);
    exit;
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([
    "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages" => [["role" => "user", "content" => $prompt]],
    "temperature" => 0.7
]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Authorization: Bearer $apiKey",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]);

logMessage("Sending request to OpenAI API");
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    logMessage("Curl error: " . curl_error($ch));
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch)]);
} else {
    logMessage("Received response from API");
    logMessage("Response: " . $response);
    echo $response;
}

curl_close($ch);
logMessage("Script ended");
?>

Issue
When I try to access the file via www.domain.com/proxy.php I can see activity in the log file. However, when I try to run the game and have it call the file then there isn't even any activity..
I've been trying to implement the needed headers that the error message says is missing. I have done so to the best of my abilities but it keeps on claiming that there are headers missing.

The proxy has the correct permissions and is readable and executable. I'm hosting on freehosting.com.
Can anyone see what may cause the the block?

Please include error messages as text within the question

Not sure where exactly that screenshot is from, but it doesn't really clarify, whether the preflight request or the actual request had a problem. Can you please check the browser console, it should have more specific details.

Small thing: in the preflight handler you redefine the same header again, that's redundant and might even be an issue. I would also think wherever you see that error you are probably able to get more details on the returned headers which would be nice to see included in the question. Your server hoster might be stripping or changing certain headers as well (perhaps some security features are active?)

Header redefinition shouldn't be an issue actually (but still redundant). The PHP docs state that equal headers get replaced. Side note: In pure PHP scripts, omit the closing ?> tag at the end, this will prevent outputting accidental whitespaces that may come after the closing tag

If you see nothing in the logs then the request probably never reaches PHP. I'd guess your webserver doesn't route OPTIONS requests through the PHP interpreter. Check the webserver config.

A preflight request should be properly answered with an Access-Control-Allow-Methods header.

There are several issues with your code. In particular: 1) you're including the same Access-Control-Allow-Origin header twice in responses to OPTIONS requests; 2) as pointed out by @KIKOSoftware, you fail to include an Access-Control-Allow-Methods header in responses to preflight requests; 3) you misclassify all OPTIONS requests as preflight requests. Unless you're intimately familiar with CORS, you shouldn't implement it "by hand"; instead, you should rely on some CORS middleware library.
